# How to scroll large texts in paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) to create a (non-interactive) display. I have fixed area inside which I want to show some text. When the text is large, I want to clip the text so as to show only the part inside the fixed area is visible to the user. In addition, in that case, I want to scroll the text left-to-right repeatedly.

As far as I could read in the paperjs documentation, there is no strait forward way to achieve this (.
So, I am thinking of doing the following:

- Determine if the text is larger than the container box. Could not find an easy way to do this. Thinking of having a simple heuristic function - which goes by the number of characters in the text.
- Clip the text within the container box. I have not figured out yet but it appears possible.
- Change the anchor point gradually to the left to create the scrolling effect. Again to determine how far to go, we would need the size of the text - but may need to depend on a heuristic function again.

May be the upcoming feature [AreaText](http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem/) would make doing this easier. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this in the meantime. Thanks.

Please let me know if there are samples in plain canvas or in another js framework ...

Answer (score 2):

If PaperJS works well for your app but you need scrolling text, you could make a hybrid app that uses both a PaperJS canvas and a native html5 canvas. The native html5 canvas could just do the scrolling text.

Since you ask for ideas...Here's an autoscrolling text script that I did a while back.

You're welcome to use the code as a starting point for your scrolling script. It word-wraps sentences into paragraphs and then displays them on an auto-scrolling html canvas.

When you need to display some text you could temporarily overlay your PaperJS canvas with this scrolling text html5 canvas and remove the html5 canvas when done displaying the text.  Its would also be easy to give the user control of the scrolling using an html input-range control.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var Paragraphs=( function(){
  function Paragraphs(x,y,maxwidth,fontsize,fontface){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.originalY=y;
    this.maxwidth=maxwidth;
    this.fontsize=fontsize;
    this.fontface=fontface;
    this.autoLineAdvance=true;
    this.writeCount=0;
    this.p=[];
    this.nextTime=0;
    this.duration=1000/60*1;
    this.viewheight=150;
    this.offsetY=0;
    this.canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.totalHeight=0;
  };
  Paragraphs.prototype.addParagraph=function(text){ this.p.push(text); }
  Paragraphs.prototype.autoscroll=function(viewportHeight){
    this.viewheight=ch;
    this.offsetY=ch;
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animatescroll.bind(this));                
  };
  Paragraphs.prototype.animatescroll=function(time){
    var that=this;
    if(this.offsetY>0){
      requestAnimationFrame(that.animatescroll.bind(that));
    }else{log('done');}
    if(time<this.nextTime){return;}
    this.nextTime=time+this.duration;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(this.canvas,this.x,this.offsetY);
    this.offsetY-=0.50;
  };
  Paragraphs.prototype.lineAdvance=function(){this.y+=this.fontsize*1.286*1.5};
  Paragraphs.prototype.drawOffCanvas=function(){
    var y=0;
    var lineCount=0;
    var lineHeight = this.fontsize*1.286;
    var lineAdvance=lineHeight*1.5;
    this.canvas.width=this.maxwidth;
    this.canvas.height=this.height();
    this.ctx.textBaseline='top';
    this.ctx.font = this.fontsize + "px " + this.fontface;
    for(var i=0;i<this.p.length;i++){
      var words=this.p[i].split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var space='';
      for (var n=0; n<words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + space + words[n];
        space=' ';
        if (this.ctx.measureText(testLine).width > this.maxwidth) {
          this.ctx.fillText(line, 1, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
          space='';
        } else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      this.ctx.fillText(line, 1,y);
      y+=lineAdvance;
    }
  };
  Paragraphs.prototype.height=function(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.textBaseline='top';
    ctx.font = this.fontsize + "px " + this.fontface;
    var lineHeight = this.fontsize*1.286;
    var writeCount=0;
    var height=lineHeight*(this.p.length-1)*0.50;
    var line,space;
    for(var i=0;i<this.p.length;i++){
      var words=this.p[i].split(' ');
      line=space='';
      if((writeCount++)>0){ height+=lineHeight; }
      for (var n=0; n<words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + space + words[n];
        space=' ';
        if (ctx.measureText(testLine).width > this.maxwidth) {
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          height+=lineHeight;
          space='';
        } else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
    }
    height+=lineHeight;
    ctx.restore();
    this.totalHeight=height;
    return(height);
  }
  return(Paragraphs);
})();


var d=new Paragraphs(35,20,200,14,'verdana');
d.addParagraph("I am using paper.js to create a (non-interactive) display. I have fixed area inside which I want to show some text. When the text is large, I want to clip the text so as to show only the part inside the fixed area is visible to the user. In addition, in that case, I want to scroll the text left-to-right repeatedly.");
d.addParagraph("Please let me know if there are samples in plain canvas or in another js framework ...");
d.drawOffCanvas();
d.autoscroll();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Text scrolls in from the bottom<br>Be patient or click full page mode</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```